# shell script of grep single line in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file with the following format:

```
123 2 3 48 85.64 85.95
Park ParkName Location
12 2.2 3.2 48 5.4 8.9
```

Now I could like to write a shell script to extract lines from this file. 
The first item from each line is a kind of flag. For different flags, I will make different process.
See my code below:

```
head= ` echo "$line" | grep -P "^\d+" `    
if [ "$head" != "" ]; then  
 (do something...)  
fi  
head=` echo "$line" | grep -P "^[A-Z]+" `  
if [ "$head" != "" ]; then  
 (do something...)  
fi
```

The code works. But I dislike the complicated way of writing 2 "if".
I would like to have something simple like:

```
if [ "$head" != "" ]; then  
 (do something...)  
elif [ "$head" != "" ]; then  
 (do something...)  
fi
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm surprised that your code _works_!  How could `head= echo "$line" | grep -P "^\d+"` work?

Comment: head=` echo "$line" | grep -P "^\d+" ` @devnull  --- first time to post questions... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about pure bash solution? Bash has a built-in regexp functionality, that you trigger with `~` character.
Be aware though that processing huge files with bash read line will not yield in optimal performance..

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

while read line
do
  echo "read [$line]"
  if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9] ]]; then
    echo '  Processing numeric line'

  elif [[ $line =~ ^[A-Za-z]  ]]; then
    echo '  Processing a text line'
  fi
done < $file
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I guess it would fulfill your requirement

**file**

> 123 2 3 48 85.64 85.95
>
> Park ParkName Location
>
> 12 2.2 3.2 48 5.4 8.9

**script.sh**

```
while read line

do

echo $line | grep -qP "^\d+" && echo "Line starts with Numbers"    
echo $line | grep -qP "^[a-zA-Z]+" && echo "Line Starts with String"

done < file
```

**Output:-**

```
bash script.sh
```

> Line starts with Numbers
>
> Line Starts with String
>
> Line starts with Numbers

Comment: sorry @Vasanta Koli, your answer is absolutely correct. meanwhile, i can see here the code has a good sense of grammar. However, julumme answer that first. First come first served. I would like to vote to you, but I dont have enough reputation points here.